# Mercurial Keyring Prompts for Password Every time

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-keyring

I am using the [mercurial key-ring extension](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension) to store the password to my remote repository on BitBucket, so I don't have to enter it every time I push to the remote repository. Ironically, it asks me for the password to unlock the key-ring every time I need to access it; thereby completely mitigating its purpose to me. What am I doing wrong?

In my global mercurial config (~/.hgrc) I have the following lines:

```
[extensions]
hgext.mercurial_keyring = /etc/mercurial/mercurial_keyring.py
```

In my repo mercurial config (.hg/hgrc), I have:

```
[paths]
default = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo
```

Example:

```
> hg out
> comparing with https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo
> Please enter password for encrypted keyring:
```

I have tried uninstalling the keyring and trying again. I've also played about with configuration settings I've found online to no avail. I also couldn't find anything on encrypted keyring and non-encrypted keyring in regards to mercurial.

How can I get it so that I don't have to enter a password at all when I perform actions to the remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was already the case at the time the question was asked, but now the solution is directly explained in the [keyring extension wiki link in your question](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension).

Just enabling the keyring extension is not enough, you also need to tell Mercurial the remote repo and the username in the config file.

Quote from the link:

> 3.2. Repository configuration (HTTP)
>
> Edit repository-local `.hg/hgrc` and save there the remote repository
>   path and the username, but do not save the password. For example:
>
> ```
> [paths] 
> myremote = https://my.server.com/hgrepo/someproject
>
> [auth] 
> myremote.schemes = http https 
> myremote.prefix = my.server.com/hgrepo
> myremote.username = mekk
> ```
>
> Simpler form with url-embedded name can also be used:
>
> ```
> [paths]
> bitbucket = https://User@bitbucket.org/User/project_name/
> ```
>
> Note: if both the username and password are given in `.hg/hgrc`, the
>   extension will use them without using the password database. If the
>   username is not given, extension will prompt for credentials every
>   time, also without saving the password. So, in both cases, it is
>   effectively reverting to the default behaviour.

---

Note that you don't need to specify *all* the information shown in those examples.

On my machine (Mercurial 5.0.2 on Windows), I'm using a simpler form which also works for multiple repos.
This is a 1:1 copy from my actual config file:

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring = 

[auth]
bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/
bb.username = christianspecht
```

This uses the keyring extension to save the password for the user `christianspecht`, for all remote repos whose URL starts with `https://bitbucket.org/`.

The prefix `bb` can be freely picked, so you can use this to save multiple URLs/usernames at once.

This works perfectly well *(at least until Bitbucket drops Mercurial support in a few weeks...)* - it asks for the password once, then it's automatically saved and it never asks again.

Answer (score -1):

> it asks me for the password to unlock the key-ring. What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. Read the [keyring docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring), password *for accessing keyring* **must** be provided once for session

Comment: But what's the point of a keyring that requires you to enter the password to it *every* time it is accessed?

Comment: @Badger, the point is that it doesn't ask me once a session, it instead asks me for it every time I push (pull, out, etc.) to my bitbucket account.

Comment: I have the same problem - keyring password is requested for *each* sub repo I want to check out:( Useless as is.